# Configuration / mapping issue in Angular 2

Tags: typescript, angular

I'm trying to import Http and Response from "angular2/http" like this:

```
import { Http, Response }   from 'angular2/http';
```

When I run my app, though, I get a 404 error when the system tries to find:

```
http://localhost:19102/Scripts/angular2/angular2.dev.js/http
```

I assume there is something wrong with the way I have things mapped, but I can't solve the problem.

I am running this in Visual Studio 2015.

Here is my system.js.config file:

```
(function (global) {

// map tells the System loader where to look for things
var map = {
    'app': 'app', // 'dist',
    'rxjs': 'node_modules/rxjs',
    'angular2-in-memory-web-api': 'node_modules/angular2-in-memory-web-api',
    'angular2': 'Scripts/angular2/angular2.dev.js'
};

// packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
var packages = {
    'app': { main: 'main.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'rxjs': { defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'angular2-in-memory-web-api': { defaultExtension: 'js' }
};

var packageNames = [
  '@angular/common',
  '@angular/compiler',
  '@angular/core',
  '@angular/http',
  '@angular/platform-browser',
  '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic',
  '@angular/router',
  '@angular/router-deprecated',
  '@angular/testing',
  '@angular/upgrade'
];

// add package entries for angular packages in the form '@angular/common': { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' }
packageNames.forEach(function (pkgName) {
    packages[pkgName] = { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
});

var config = {
    packages: packages,
    map: map,
    bundles: {
        'angular2': ['angular2/core', 'angular2/platform/browser']
    }
}

// filterSystemConfig - index.html's chance to modify config before we register it.
if (global.filterSystemConfig) { global.filterSystemConfig(config); }

System.config(config);
```

})(this);

P.S. I am an absolute newcomer to Angular, so I am still trying to figure out how things work. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your imports from

```
import { Http, Response } from 'angular2/http';
```

to

```
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
```

The reason for that is because in Angular 2 RC1 the scope for angular modules has been changed to `@angular`. It used to be `angular2` in beta which is what you are importing in the code you are showing.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Unfortunately, when I change it like that, I get a typescript compilation error "cannot find module '@angular/http'.

Comment: Do you have the angular 2 RC1 modules in your `node_modules\@angular` folder?

Comment: As far as I can tell I have installed 2.0.0-beta.17. I didn't know that Angular2 was out in a release candidate already. Where do I find that?

Comment: Never mind, I found it. Thanks. I hadn't realized it changed in the week or so that I've been working with it.